# MVC3 - dropdown list to show stored value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have an update page, there is a field call ingredientname, the dropdown lists all the ingredients, but how do I bind the value stored against in each ingredient for a recipe.

In my controller I have the following code which will list all ingredients in dropdown;

```
foreach (RecipeIngredient recipeIngredient in recipe.RecipeIngredientList)
{
    rIngredients.Add(recipeIngredient);
}
```

on the update page I want the text box to show a value.

Comment: I don't get it: why you populate a collection with all the value from another collection? I mean, there could be lot of good reasons, but unless you show us some other code, this thing you posted is a little useless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%: Html.DropDownList("BusinessTypeId", new SelectList(Model.BusinessTypes, "BusinessTypeId", "BusinessTypeName"), "Select an Option")%>`

Here the value is BusinessTypeId and name is BusinessTypeName

```
 foreach (BusinessType businessType in _businessDetails.BusinessTypes)
                {

                        businessType.BusinessTypeName = businessType.SpanishBusinessTypeName;

                    businessTypeLst.Add(businessType);
                }
```

//Page

var _ddValue = $('#BusinessTypeId').val();

assign it to textbox

$('#txtboxId').val(_ddValue );